# How to use ls within program on a specified file path?

Tags: c++, ls, execv

Creating my own shell program for a project. Currently trying to `fork()` then perform `execv()` by sending the location where ls is executed and then sending arguments for ls which is file path and options.

So far the `ls` output is only showing me what's in the directory where my shell program is located.

```
// directoryPath[] is  /home/pi/cs460
// option[] i use NULL or -al for the time being
```

```
void lsProcess(char directoryPath[], char option[])
{
    string lsLocation = "/bin/ls";
    char * lsPlace = new char[lsLocation.size() + 1];
    strcpy(lsPlace, lsLocation.c_str());

    char * args[] = {lsPlace, NULL, directoryPath};

    execv(args[0], args);
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `char * args[] = {lsPlace, NULL, directoryPath};` be `char * args[] = {lsPlace, directoryPath, NULL};`?  When `ls` is parsing your argument array, it hits the null at args[1] and stops parsing.  Also, you should probably verify that `directoryPath` is null terminated...

EDIT

If you want a place holder for options, you need to include the one element array that only contains null to represent an empty string and then add another null at the end

```
char options[1];
options[0] = 0;

char * args[] = {lsPlace, options, directoryPath, NULL};
```

Comment: The same thing was done for directory[] and option[] like lsPlace before being passed in.

Comment: Sure, in this case, what about when somebody else calls it. ;)  Anyway, the NULL in the middle of your array is what keeps `ls` from listing `directoryPath`, and there MUST be a NULL after `directoryPath`.